# Safest way to downgrade RabbitMq

Tags: heroku, rabbitmq

We want to downgrade RabbitMq to a smaller plan but obviously don't want to loose data or have outages. We are using RabbitMq with Heroku and can't seem to find any documentation.

It seems like we need to use a federated queue to divert messages to a new queue, but was wondering if, for example Heroku has a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what i have seen and have done in the past upgrade or downgrade is only possible for a shared plan , i think you are referring to a shared plan itself.

For sure there will be some downtime , but of course if you plan it well you can minimize it. Data loss can only happen if the execution is flawed.

We followed the recommended approach and i am quoting verbatim

> "*Create the new plan and point your publishers to the new plan. Let your consumers empty the queues on the old plan and then point them to the new plan and finally delete the old plan.*"

We did the exercise multiple times on two test instances since we had to notify the pub/sub applications groups as well so there is some management/coordination involved as well.

[image]

Reference page can be found here https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/heroku.html